# Nlog not logging if archived logs in directory

Tags: logging, nlog

In our setup, we have a service running in a background that should log into a rolling file. We are using Common.Logging as a abstraction layer.

At some point it stopped logging, we had a directory of files

- ...
- Product.WindowsService.log.20160615.txt
- Product.WindowsService.log.20160616.txt
- Product.WindowsService.log.20160617.txt

and then nothing: no Product.WindowsService.log.txt file, no archived file with next date (Product.WindowsService.log.20160618.txt).

The service was still running, just no logs.

Then we deleted the archived log files and immediately the log Product.WindowsService.log.txt file was created and was being filled with data (no restart or anything).

The NLog version is 4.3.3

Unfortunately we didn't set internal logging so information is scarce.

Our configuration file:

```
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Product.Log" />
  </extensions>
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="D:\Product\TEST\Logs\Product.WindowsService.log.txt" archiveFileName="D:\Product\TEST\Logs\Product.WindowsService.log.{#}.txt" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Date" archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd" maxArchiveFiles="7" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} | ${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5} | ${threadid:padding=3} | ${logger} | ${message} ${exception:format=tostring:maxInnerExceptionLevel=99}" />
    <target name="colored-console" type="ColoredConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="true" errorStream="true" layout="${date} ${level:uppercase=true:padCharacter=.}${literal:text=\t}(${logger}) ${message} ${exception}" />
    <target name="dblog" type="ProductDbLog" layout="${longdate} | ${threadid:padding=3} | ${message} ${exception:format=tostring:maxInnerExceptionLevel=99}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="colored-console">
      <filters>
        <when condition="starts-with('${logger}','Quartz') and (level &lt; LogLevel.Warn)" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile">
    </logger>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="dblog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Any idea what could cause such behavior?

Comment: If you enable the internal log, please create an issue on github when it happens again.

Comment: And there is a fix in NLog 4.3.4 which is highly related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in NLog 4.3.4.